# How to detect slow code or plugin

Tags: mysql, php, wordpress

I don't have much experience with WordPress and I don't know where to start. There is a website which is running very very slow. The hosting company helped me to detect that it's because some piece of code tries to connect to IP `85.214.232.25`, which is `phat-reaction.com`, but it can't, and it does that when generating the page.

This is a pretty standard WordPress installation running theme [Belief](http://themeforest.net/item/belief-church-wordpress-theme/4068949). It has some reasonable-looking plugins installed: Easy Columns, Formularze (https://ideasilo.wordpress.com/), Free Social Slider by ARScode, Google Analytics, Jetpack z WordPress.com, MailPoet Newsletters, PWA+PHP Picasa Web Albums for Wordpress, Simple Custom Post Order, Simple Lightbox, Stop Spammers Spam Control, Traffic Counter Widget, WordPress Hit Counter, WP-Optimize, Youtube Playlist Thumbs. None of them seem to be related to phat-reaction.com.

It's also possible that the bad code is injected in some widget, or where else to look? Is it possible to debug it somehow from the WordPress account? I could potentially grep the code but firstly, I don't have access to SSH at this moment, and secondly, the bad fragment of code could be stored in the database.

Comment: First, get your ssh access. Without that there's little you can really do.

Comment: SSH is being sorted out. I can download scripts through FTP apparently and debug on my own computer. I will try to grep the code and see if there is anything obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search in Google for P3 plugin profiler. This WordPress plugin will check all of your plugins and detect which one take more resources from your webserver. Also search for "what the file" plugin to check your code. You can also make some queries and search strings to your WordPress web site with "String Locator WordPress plugin". This is the method I usually prefer to start. You should get your Server and Cpanel information for more deep search.

Comment: I disabled all plugins and it didn't help, so my guess is that it's either the Belief theme or some other code added to a page. Will the P3 plugin help in that case?

Comment: P3 is just a perfomance metrics WordPress Plugin, in your case you should try Theme Authenticity Checker (TAC), and scan with Sucuri WordPress Plugin and Exploit Scanner WordPress Plugin. But i repeat, for better results you should have at least an FTP access to your Server for better scan. Usually you will find an eval code, or in your wp-content file-->uploads or on your Theme js-or-php files. Google for wordpress security scanner plugins, try to install every plugin one by one(dont forget after to disable and delete all of them and keep just on or two) and scan your WordPress files.

Comment: This code was being called when generating EVERY page: `$googlefontsSeraliazed = wp_remote_get("http://phat-reaction.com/googlefonts.php?format=php");`. The result was cached but that's not enough when the remote server is down and the call always fails. This doesn't say much good about the quality of the Belief - Church WordPress Theme code. Thanks for help.

Comment: Hi again ( a bit late response :( ) so give a try to **Query Monitor**  https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/ the plugin will do the job and works with PHP7 also (P3 profiler is outdated and you won't take results if you run in php7, if you need more depth scan, you need to gain access to your web server..

Answer (score 1):

Whenever I find a site is going slow I run it through http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt/ it generally gives you some insight into whats slowing it down and where its coming from.

Comment: Very nice tool. It's not exactly what I asked for in my question, because it won't allow me to detect which part of which php script is running slow (since in this case it was slowing down the generation of the main page), however, it will be an useful tool nevertheless. Thanks.

Comment: I did a bit more rooting around for you.

Comment: "$googlefontsSeraliazed = wp_remote_get("http://phat-reaction.com/googlefonts.php?format=php");" is obviously getting a font which it has to download if the browser or machine does not already have the font installed. I would imagine that the fact it has to download the font every-time could be the cause of the slow down. You could google "web safe fonts" and change the font to one of the "web safe fonts" in your css. The belief theme uses fontello and phat-reaction.com is the best alternative to google font api's.